# Viewport and render artifact with distant objects

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, camera, transforms

Using the default scene, if I select everything (cube, camera, lamp) and move everything very far away (say X = 999999, Y = 888888, Z = 777777) from the World Origin, the camera sees and renders the cube and the grid floor as if they were shaken objects in all 3 axis.

That problem happens at least in Blender 2.92 Release and Blender 2.83.13 LTS.

What's the cause of that problem ?
How to solve it ?

My goal is to be able to move any object, any rigged character, any light and any camera anywhere in a huge world (X, Y and Z ranging from -999999 to 999999), without such visual artifact.

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Answer (score 3):

Internally, Blender uses [floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) to represent vertex coordinates. Floating point numbers can represent a very wide range of values, but they grow increasingly imprecise at very large or very small scales. The [Working Limits section of the Blender documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/advanced/limits.html#space) gives some example precisions at various scales.

If you want to work with very large coordinate values, you can use [the Unit Scale scene property](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.92/scene_layout/scene/properties.html#units) to globally scale everything in the scene into the numerically stable range. Of course, this has the consequence of making smaller values less precise, so you ultimately just need to pick a scale and stick to it.

Comment: I looked at the Blender documentation sections you pointed me. Following the rule of thumb, I will separate my world in many parts, to always have values within a reliable range of some 10,000.units (meters in my case). Thanks a lot, Alexis.